# Classic ASP on IIS fails over network

Tags: ms-access, iis, asp-classic

I have inherited a classic ASP application running on IIS web server and an MS Access back end database. The choice of using MS Access and Classic ASP was taken before I arrived. The back end database schema is fairly extensive with some complex SQL and dozens of tables etc.  We aim to migrate the application to another server running SQL Server 2012 and eventually re-implement the application to ASP.NET.  But we have an issue with the application that needs fixed now.  To complicate matters the server hosting the application is a server I am not allowed access to and must request changes through ICT.  Although I have requested to be able to access the IIS logs on the server at least.

The problem is, if we set certain criteria that limits the records returned to a few hundred it works fine.  But if we select criteria that we know will return rows more than a few hundred it fails with the chrome browser message (EDGE and IE are similar with the same main message)

[image]

Obviously I had a Google for this and I tried all of the following in this YouTube solution (except I cannot turn off the anti-virus as not allowed)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RBwtQEWt6L0

I looked at the issue using the Console in Developer Tools for browser.  Chrome does not really show anything but Edge gives an error that I don't feel is relevant as works for smaller number of record retrievals.  See image below

[image]

I asked our ICT to check the IIS Interval properties but not sure they have set this correctly and would appreciate advise on this property.

How do we resolve this please?  Is there some intricate IIS settings we need to change? Again, we do intend to migrate and re-implement the application in ASP.NET but need this issue resolved for now.  Thank you

Comment: Look for problems in IIS error log

Comment: @4dmonster Thanks for prompt response.  Yes, I have requested permissions to map a drive to the logs location and found a couple of tools that allow searching the logs.  Do you think the answer will definitely be in the logs?

Comment: i suggest timeout or resource low kind of problem at IIS.

Comment: try to run iis application pool as 32 bit, try to restart the iis, clear browser cache and history, increase iis site execution time out value. Delete temporary files from c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v.######\Temporary ASP.NET Files and 
Delete temporary files from c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework64\v.######\Temporary ASP.NET Files